# Is there a way to know if there are more than one Spring Context in use?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have 2 spring boot applications - an `API service` and a `library`.

`library` generates a non-executable, imporatable JAR, which is imported and used by `API service`. Here is the pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>

        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>library</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>library</name>
    <description>Library Integration</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <oauth2.version>2.1.1.RELEASE</oauth2.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>${oauth2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Some other info about `library` project:

1. It does not have a class with main method i.e., no @SpringBootApplication
2. It has a Configuration class that scans components:

   @Configuration

   @ComponentScan("com.example.library")

   public class LibraryConfiguration {}
3. In /resources/META-INF/spring.factories we read this configuration:

   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=
   com.example.library.LibraryConfiguration

This had to be done, as when we are importing `library` in `API service` project, `API service` is not able to find the classes which we want to use there. These classes are beans and hence need to be initialized.

For `API service` project, pom is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>api-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>api service</name>
    <description>api service</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JUnit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>library</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

APIs of `API service` project use methods of `library` project. The project works fine, all the APIs work.

However, I would like to confirm that only one Spring context is in use and not 2. When `API service` is started, it has its own context. Then it gets `library` dependency, which **might** create its own context and initialise beans of library project.

Ideally, I would like that there is only one context and that is of `API service` project. Is there a way to ensure this?

Comment: There is just one, the library doesn't create a context.

Comment: @M.Deinum Is there a way to verify this?

Comment: First you should check if you have the `@ComponentScan` in your application and second why do you use different spring boot versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a similar Spring Boot Project few days back. This question didn't cross my mind ever. Reason being, How context get created and there can't be two Contexts.

1. You start your application by providing a main Class ( You can't provide two).
2. Application Context / BeanFactory are Spring managed Bean, Your Library is not different from any Spring boot dependency ( Spring MVC, Spring Security). In a single Application instance it will not create two different Contexts.

In Order to Verify. Write Below code in any Spring Managed Bean. If Spring boot comes up and doesn't give any Exception e.g. Multiple Beans of type ApplicationContext  found. That will be a proof.

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
```

Alternatively, Include a Actuator dependency and hit below URL . It will give you all beans created. Context is just a bean, Check if there are multiple Beans.

```
http://<address>:<management-port>/beans.
```

Answer (score 1):

library does not create the context. However you can check it by Autowiring the ApplicationContext in your main boot class and printing the ID and display name for example :-

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

```
System.out.println(applicationContext.getDisplayName());
System.out.println(applicationContext.getId());
```

Answer (score 1):

There will not be two application context for your case since you don't have `SpringBoot` main class in library. In `springboot` application context is created when `SpringApplication.run(this,args)` is called.

Comment: what would have happened if I had one, in the library?

Comment: Since you said APIs works fine and if you are able to autowire the beans from library it should be fine.